# What is the explicit smooth structure of an embedded submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Here is a quotation from Chapter 5 in "Introduction to smooth manifolds" by J. Lee.

> Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary. An embedded submanifold of $M$ is a subset $S \subseteq M$ that is a manifold (without boundary) in the subspace topology, endowed with a smooth structure with resect to which the inclusion map $S\to M$ is a smooth embedding.

My questions are the following:

- What is the topology on $S$?
- What is the smooth structure on $S$?

In my thought, $\{i^{-1}(U\cap S)\mid U \in \mathcal{O}(M)\}$ is the topology on $S$ with the topology $\mathcal{O}(M)$ on $M$.

For the second question, I think $\mathcal{A}_{S}:=\{(i^{-1}(U\cap S), \phi\circ i)\mid (U,\phi)\in \mathcal{A}_{M}\}$ is the smooth structure on $S$ with the smooth structure $\mathcal{A}_{M}$ on $M$, but it seems to be odd for me if $\mathrm{dim}(S)<\mathrm{dim}(M)$ because the dimension of the image under $\phi\circ i$ is $\mathrm{dim}(M)$, which is absurd.

Is there anything wrong with the above discussion?

Comment: As the inclusion is an smooth embedding then the topology of $S$ is the induced topology from $M$. Also, as you noted $\mathcal{A}_{S}:=\{(i^{-1}(U\cap S), \phi\circ i)\mid (U,\phi)\in \mathcal{A}_{M}\}$ is the smooth structure in $S$, however the rank of $\partial(\phi\circ i)$ could be arbitrary, it doesn't need to be maximal, it will depend on the dimension of $S$. By example: the inclusion map of a point, or a line, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ cannot be a local diffeomorphism

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for you comment, but I do not know the symbol $\partial(\phi\circ i)$. Is it the differential of $\phi\circ i$? In order for $(i^{-1}(U\cap S), \phi\circ i)$ to be a chart on $S$, I think the dimension of the image under $\phi\circ i$ must be equal to $\mathrm{dim}S$.

Comment: yes, the differential, maybe it must be written $T_p(\phi \circ i)=T_{i(p)}\phi \circ T_p i$

Comment: I'm really sorry, but what is the symbol $T_p i$? Is it related to the tangent space?

Comment: $T_p f$ is the tangential of a function $f:M\to N$ between manifolds. Sometimes called incorrectly "differential" (it is incorrect because the differential is a form or covector, however the tangential is a map between tangent spaces)

Comment: the books of John Lee are many times hard to "follow" (hard to get the picture about something), behind the formalism the simplicity of the subject is hidden. An algebraic approach is generally easier to understand and follow, as in the books of Loring Tu. However the books of Lee are a lot more complete, they show a lot more topics and theorems.

Comment: You omitted a word in the passage you quoted. It actually says "a subset $S\subseteq M$ that is a manifold (without boundary) in the subspace **topology**, ...." That answers your first question.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A priori, the smooth structure on $ S $ can have no relationship to that of $ M $. However, as mentioned and proven later in the book, for any embedded submanifold $ S\subseteq M $, its smooth structure must be given by the slice charts of $ S $. More specifically, any chart $ (U,\phi=(x^1,\ldots,x^n)) $ of $ M $ such that $ \phi(S\cap U) $ is given by $ x^{k+1}=\cdots=x^n=0 $, where $ k=\dim S $, gives rise to the chart $ (U\cap S,(x^1,\ldots,x^k)) $ of $ S $.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I overlooked the result.

Comment: I understand there is no relations between the smooth structure on $S$ and one on $M$. But, is it related to the inclusion map? I want to understand how the inclusion map relates to the smooth structure on $S$.

Comment: the smooth structures of $S$ and $M$ **are** related from the beginning via the inclusion map, it is incorrect to say that there is no relation

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. We can equip $S$ with the smooth structure induced from the inclusion mapping, but we can also equip it with another smooth structure that is not related to the inclusion map, right?

Comment: @kumegon yes, but in this case probably doesn't make sense to talk of a "submanifold". As submanifolds there are essentially two possible kind of smooth structures: an structure induced by an immersion map, and an structure induced by an embedding (a specific type of immersion map). In both cases the immersion map is locally an embedding, and so the differential structure of a submanifold are ever related to the smooth structure of the parent manifold

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks to you, I can completely understand this topic!!